# Добавить класс активному элементу jquery

Tags: jquery

Привет. Задача такая: есть несколько товаров и детальная инфа по каждому.
Необходимо при клике на первью товара

1. Выделить активное превью (добавить класс active-other)
2. Показать товар (добавить класс active-item)

Я сделал только 1 пункт. А как сделать чтобы появлялся активный товар?Помогите

```js
$(".other-item").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".other-item").removeClass('active-other');
  $(this).addClass('active-other');
});
```

```css
.product {
  display: none;
}

.active-item {
  display: block!important;
}
.active-other {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--товар подробнее-->
<div class="product active-item">
  <img class="sp-imag" src="img/tovar1.png">
  <h3>товар 1</h3>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <img class="sp-imag" src="img/tovar2.png">
  <h3>товар 2</h3>
</div>
<!--превью товаров-->
<div class="other" id="other">
  <div class="other-item active-other">
    <img src="img/tovar1.png"/>
    <h5>товар 1</h5>
    <p>215 руб.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="other-item">
    <img src="img/tovar2.png"/>
    <h5>товар 2</h5>
    <p>215 руб.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(() => {
  $('.container').each(function() {
    const $container = $(this),
      $otherItems = $container.find('.other-item'),
      $products = $container.find('.product');

    $otherItems.click(function() {
      const $this = $(this),
        index = $this.data('product-id');

      $otherItems.removeClass('active-other');
      $this.addClass('active-other');
      
      $products.removeClass('active-item')
        .filter('[data-id="' + index + '"]').addClass('active-item');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.product {
  display: none;
}

.active-item {
  display: block!important;
}

.active-other {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!--товар подробнее-->
  <div class="product active-item" data-id="1">
    <img class="sp-imag" src="img/tovar1.png">
    <h3>товар 1</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="product" data-id="2">
    <img class="sp-imag" src="img/tovar2.png">
    <h3>товар 2</h3>
  </div>
  <!--превью товаров-->
  <div class="other" id="other">
    <div class="other-item active-other" data-product-id="1">
      <img src="img/tovar1.png"/>
      <h5>товар 1</h5>
      <p>215 руб.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="other-item" data-product-id="2">
      <img src="img/tovar2.png"/>
      <h5>товар 2</h5>
      <p>215 руб.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** Правда не очень понятно зачем в данном коде нужно `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: А как бы вы решили данную задачу? как професионал

Comment: @Виктор, я бы добавил какие-нибудь атрибуты, что бы по ним ориентироваться, мало-ли по какой причине вздумается переставить порядок в одном блоке и не переставить в другом (скажем из-за условностей позиционирования при верстке), иначе блоки будут ссылаться не на те превью что надо. Плюс добавить бы контейнер, на случай, если этот блок будет использован на одной странице дважды.

Comment: например если добавить атрибут data_item и каждому товару уникальный номер.Как можно будет обратиться к нему и присвоить класс?

Comment: @Виктор, обновил, добавился контейнер `.container`, атрибуты `data-product-id`, `data-id` и собственно изменился обработчик, теперь разницы нет в каком порядке стоят элементы и можно использовать этот блок несколько раз на странице.

Comment: Спасибо!А как с вами можно связаться?есть несколько вопросов (не за спасибо))

Comment: @Виктор, добавил скайп в профиль